# subset of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df like

```
Sample  Percentage  Attribute1  Attribute2
1_A       12.3         xxxx        yyyy    
1_A       5.0         aaaa        bbbb    
2_B       10           ccccc       ddddd
```

For each sample, I want to choose the row which has the maximum value in Percentage  and make a dataframe df1. If there exist multiple percentages for a sample (such as 1_A), I would like to make a dataframe df2  in which all the rows other than the one that was chosen for df1. In the example above: df1 will have rows of Samples 1_A and 2_B and df2 will have row from Sample 2B. I tried `groupby('Percentage')` followed by `apply(list)` but was not successful for df1.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('Percentage').drop_duplicates('Sample',keep='last')
Out[1046]: 
  Sample  Percentage Attribute1 Attribute2
2    2_B        10.0      ccccc      ddddd
0    1_A        12.3       xxxx       yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by first sorting the dataframe by `Percentage`, so the higher percentages are at the bottom. Then, `groupby` the `Sample` column, and take the last row using `tail(1)` to create `df1`. Then, to create `df2`, just find the rows of `df` whose indices are not in `df1`:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('Percentage').groupby('Sample').tail(1)

df2 = df[~df.index.isin(df1.index)]

>>> df1
  Sample  Percentage Attribute1 Attribute2
2    2_B        10.0      ccccc      ddddd
0    1_A        12.3       xxxx       yyyy
>>> df2
  Sample  Percentage Attribute1 Attribute2
1    1_A         5.0       aaaa       bbbb
```